# Solve the following linear differential equation with constant coefficient.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

In the above image, (Example 13) I have formed the Auxiliary equation i.e. And tried to solve the equation by "real root theorem". But could not find the solution.

Comment: So the equation is $$y^{(4)}-4y'''+8y''-8y'+4y=0$$??

Comment: Yes. It is the Question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
p(m)
 &= m^4 - 4m^3 + 8m^2 - 8m + 4 \\
 &= \left(m^2 - 2m + 2\right)^2
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful. But I m having one doubt i.e. "Is real root theorem always applicable , as in this question I cannot find the zero's of this polynomial by using real root theorem

Comment: @AkshieDhiman see update, same idea -- you can factor into complex roots instead of real roots and end up with trigonometric solutions using De Moivre's formula

Comment: Okay thank you so much